# Where can I find formal grammars?

Tags: syntax, grammar, resource-request

Where can I find formal grammars? By 'formal grammar' I mean 'a mathematically precise set of rules that generate all (or at least a significant portion of) the grammatical sentences of a language.' It would really help me in my language learning to locate some of these formal grammars in a form that I can read (i.e. not in computer code). I'm looking for Latin and Greek specifically.

Comment: There are many formal grammars, and in many formalisms. I am not aware of any efforts to develop formal grammars for Greek or Latin, but the major European languages have been covered. See http://lingo.stanford.edu/

Answer (score 2):

A true complete and formal grammar would only hinder your desire to learn a language, so your motivation for asking for such a thing is ill-placed. You also make a false assumption about the nature of "grammar" in linguistics, that a "grammar" is only about enumerating allowed word orders. A complete grammar must include all aspects of the computation, ranging over semantics, syntax, phonology, morphology and phonetics. Also note that no grammar can be self-defining, that is, you must have some knowledge of a theory-external metatheory of the formalization, which means you need a pairing of a grammar and a meta-grammar.

You can find specific formal accounts of fragments of Greek and Latin, such as Sommerstein's book on Greek phonology, Lightfoot's work on Greek semantics and morphology, Robin Lakoff's dissertation on Latin Complementation, Redenbarger's work on Latin phonology and morphology. These works do not all use the same metatheory. If you were interested in Sanskrit, I would point you to the one extant albeit nigh impossible to use complete formal grammar of a language, the *Aṣṭādhyāyī*.

Answer (score 0):

The attempt to construct formal grammars for human languages has not yet been successful.  Don't expect much.  The most comprehensive efforts have probably been for English.  For Latin and Greek, I doubt you'll find much at all (but I haven't looked).

Comment: The first sentence has been invalid for more than 2 millennia. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81%E1%B9%87ini

Comment: No, @prash, admirable though Panini's grammar is, it doesn't approach closely the formalist goal of generating all and only the expressions of a human language.

Comment: @GregLee: In what way? Can you give examples?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I don't understand your question.  What do you want examples of?  Unsuccessful attempts?  If you want examples of ungrammatical sentences generated by Panini's grammar, I think it would be easy to find them for some who knows Sanskrit.  But I don't.

Comment: @GregLee: I meant examples of expressions generated by Panini's grammar which are not proper Sanskrit, or vice-versa. As I understand it, ever since Panini, grammatical Sanskrit has been _defined_ as whatever is consistent with Panini's grammar.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I see.  Well, in that case, modern grammarians of English could similarly declare grammatical English sentences to be exactly those generated by the grammar proposed in GPSG, then declare victory.  But I do concede your point that the sentences characterized by Panini's grammar are those characterized by Panini's grammar.

Comment: @GregLee: But you made your statement first, so I'm curious about examples of what you meant. What made you say that Panini's grammar doesn't approach the goal of generating precisely the expressions of the language?

Comment: @GregLee: Only now do I see your edit to your earlier comment, that "If you want examples of ungrammatical sentences generated by Panini's grammar, I think it would be easy to find them for some who knows Sanskrit" — I am **extremely** sceptical that such examples exist. Especially that they are easy to find for someone who knows Sanskrit: I know a bit of Sanskrit and know a lot of people who know it really well; I have _never_ heard of Panini's grammar generating ungrammatical sentences!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I have not read the Astadhyayi, only seen others' characterizations, but I was under the impression that the only parts of Sanskrit it attempts to cover are the phonology and morphology of Sanskrit.  That leaves the description of what combinations of words can be made to create new sentences of Sanskrit, that is, syntax, untouched.  That's the hard part, and that's what modern grammarians have attempted.  I don't see Panini as a real competitor.

Comment: @GregLee: Panini's grammar does discuss syntax. See e.g. Kiparsky 2002 [_On the architecture of Pāṇini's grammar_](https://web.stanford.edu/~kiparsky/Papers/hyderabad.pdf), Section 2 ("Syntax"), pages 15-31. (Also, Sanskrit syntax is relatively simple, even in the pages-long sentences of Bāṇabhaṭṭa.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, that is a useful reference, since Kiparsky knows quite a lot about modern syntax, as well other matters.  This is too long for me to quote, but I direct your attention to the Kiparsky's paragraph that begins "The grammar does not specify any constraints on the order of words in a sentence."  Kiparsky lists that and anaphora as two problems that are important in Sanskrit, have preoccupied modern grammarians, but are not dealt with at all by Panini.  It's interesting, though, that some syntactic phenomena are described in some fashion.

Comment: @GregLee: Word order and anaphora are important in modern syntactics because they are crucial to English (and other languages studied by them). In Sanskrit word order is mostly free (it's a topic of research to identify exactly when word order matters). And anaphora are simple too; see section 2.3.2 (p. 22).

Of course Panini's grammar is preoccupied by the questions important to Sanskrit rather than those important to English, and in that sense it is not a "real competitor", but that's an orthogonal question to how closely it approaches _its_ goal of generating precisely Sanskrit expressions.

Comment: @GregLee That is, the reason Panini's grammar discusses phonology and morphology so much more than syntax is because Sanskrit really does have very little syntax to discuss, and a small description covers most utterances. But I think we understand each other's view clearly enough now, so I'll stop. My intent wasn't to harrass or convince you; I was just curious what you meant. :-) Regards,